# How does Booking.com close their app programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiapplication

I just saw this trick the Booking.com app does to let you change the application's language:

[image: booking.com app]

I'm not aware of any technique to *programmatically* close an iOS app (and it's also forbidden by Apple's guidelines, but let's "pretend" that my boss wants me to do this).

How do they do it? I've tried `exit(0)` but it immediately quit like when the process crashes, while their app animates to the home screen normally. Is there maybe a private URL scheme that opens the home screen?

Comment: @Vollan I don't think it's a duplicate, because I'm interested in this specific technique from the Booking.com app. I saw that thread, and I know it's against the guidelines, I know it shouldn't be possible, yet they do it somehow. I want to know how.

Comment: @Vollan that is for macos not for iOS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try

```
// after change language dim display and follow it with this snippet
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {
    UIApplication.shared.perform(#selector(NSXPCConnection.suspend))
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
      exit(0)
     }
}
```

I have done it many times in similar cases and the app accepted without rejection

Comment: This doesn't do the quit animation like the Booking.com app. It just waits 1.5 seconds, then quits immediately like it does when you simply call `exit(0)` synchronously. There must be something else going on...

Comment: Seems this accesses a private API, could this lead to Apple rejecting the submission to AppStore?

Comment: Absolutely. You can try it, but be prepared to remove it on a moment’s notice. As you can see from Booking.com’s example, one can often get away with it.

Comment: @TamásZahola but what if Booking.com uses some other legitimate approach instead of calling a private API? This might explain why the app didn't got rejected so far.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that there's a legitimate way of doing this. But if you have a jailbroken device laying around you can check what the Booking.com app does via cycript.