# Exiting app and going back to home screen using swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am using a UITabbarController. I have 3 items/tabs inside the UITabbarController. Each tab depicts separate View controller. The list of views are as under

- Tab 1: List View Controller
- Tab 2: Favorite View Controller
- Tab 3: Contacts View Controller

Now suppose I am on Tab 3 (Contacts View controller). And here I am showing my user a UIAlertController that has a button "Exit App".

When User will click on the Exit app, the user is supposed to go out from our application and will be taken to the home screen.

I have tried following snippets from SO but nothing is working for me.

```
self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I even read to do `exit(integer number)` to exit the app but I read it also that it should not be done.

So I am really confused about what I need to do to exit app? How can I quit app and go back to home screen using Swift 4?

Comment: `exit` is as good a method as any, but it is generally not a good idea to have an "exit" button in your app; that is what the home button or bottom area of the iPhone X is for.

Comment: @Paulw11 I read it somewhere that App store does not accept that app using Exit

Comment: Why do you want to exit from the app? As @Paulw11 mentioned the user has other ways to do it, and can do so at any moment. If you finished some process and there is no natural „next step” you should rather inform the user that the action is done and revert to your initial view controller so they can do it again for another item.

Comment: no by logic I just do not want user to continue using our app. Let say have grade more then 50 you will pass other wise yo are fail.

Comment: Rethink your user interface. Do not ever offer the user an option to exit the app. If the user wants to exit, they can press the Home button. Apple doesn't want you to exit. Leave it to the user.

Comment: I am new to iOS. but I want to know, I am showing Alert controller that has button EXIT APP and there I am exiting app. still It should not be done ?

Comment: Exiting is fine. I have seen few iOS apps doing that. It's just you have to add a proper alert message to the user that why you are force closing the app to restart it. PUBG game does that on few updates.

Comment: No, do not show an "Exit App" button to the user. There's no reason to do that.

Comment: Have a look at this Apple QA: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1561/_index.html - Apple don't want you to do this.

Comment: ok so it's like : Display an alert for the user that indicates the nature of the problem and possible actions the user could take — turning on WiFi, enabling Location Services, etc. Allow the user to terminate the application at their own discretion. Thanks @PeteMorris

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Booking.com close their app programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52514516/how-does-booking-com-close-their-app-programmatically)

Comment: @Amit so what you concluded ?

Comment: Exactly that was my point. As I do not want my user to  continue using app until and unless he has to select things that are required for our business logic. For example user has to select some locations on map, but if user does not do that our app just cant continue to operate. So what should be done in this type of case?

Comment: The app should just sit there waiting for the user to select the locations or whatever.  If they don't want to do that, they can just press the home button

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to exit the app. The URL provided by @Cristik in comments also suggests that if apple will get to know about it they will send you a notice to remove it.

Better just keep the proper `UIAlert` message to tell the user what are the things required to use the app. Also proper UI navigation to first get all the required things for you business logic so that the user don't miss anything before using the app.

If you still want go with this then as @Cristik commented try this solution:

- [How does Booking.com close their app programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52514516/how-does-booking-com-close-their-app-programmatically)

Answer (score -2):

You can use:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let loginVcObj = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInVc") as! SignInVc

var vcArray = (applicationDelegate.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).viewControllers
vcArray.removeAll()
vcArray.append(loginVcObj)

(applicationDelegate.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).setViewControllers(vcArray, animated: false)
```

Comment: This code is for navigate t HomeScreen .. As you can't terminate app within your app . AppStore Team will reject your app.

Comment: so you think exit (0) is bad

Comment: and I am not using navigation controller