# how to refresh the app on the button click

Tags: ios

In this button action i need to go to the appdelegate. How to go.

I have the button in the viewcontroller .

```
@IBAction func refreshButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
}
```

In my app delegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let PAGE1model:NH_HomeModel = HomeModel(nameText: "", contactnoText: "", emailidText: "")!
    let questionlistdataSourceModel:QuestionDataSourceModel = QuestionDataSourceModel(array: nil)
    let questionlistviewModel:QuestionViewModel = QuestionViewModel(withdatasource: questionlistdataSourceModel, withmodel: PAGE1model)

    let dummyDataSource:DummyDataSourceModel = DummyDataSourceModel(array: nil)
    let dummyDataViewModel:DummyDataViewModel = DummyDataViewModel(withdatasource: dummyDataSource, withmodel: PAGE1model)

    let questionlistviewController:QuestionViewController = NH_QuestionViewController(nibName: "QuestionViewController", bundle: nil, withViewModel: questionlistviewModel, withDummyDataViewModel: dummyDataViewModel)
    navController = UINavigationController()

    self.navController!.pushViewController(questionlistviewController, animated: false)

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window!.rootViewController = navController
    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

On the button click i need to refresh the app .It should go to the app delegate.How to implement it?How to do in the refresh button.ON the refresh button clicking i need to go to the app delegate .

Comment: what you want is not clear ! do you want to call a method from app delegate on button action ?

Comment: To reach the appDelegate is simply `UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate`. but *don't* try the call `application didFinishLaunching`, this is not the way to refresh your app. you should make a different function that does exactly what you want.

Comment: @TalCohen currently i have given as let appDelegate: AppDelegate? = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
         appDelegate?.application(UIApplication.shared, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: nil) is it correct way.If not then how to do?

Comment: There's no such thing as "app refresh". ask yourself what you want to achieve. I'm guessing you want to remove the current ViewController and reload it or maybe just recreate the screen model will do the trick. but either way calling `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will not help you.

Comment: You cannot refresh your app instead try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52514516/how-does-booking-com-close-their-app-programmatically